# Output CCK items in custom template

Tags: drupal

I am working with a Drupal 6 site which relies heavily on CCK and views and I want to use the content in a webapp for iPhone.  The webapp is built in HTML and CSS and will ultimately be converted to native using PhoneGap or similar and I want to import the formatted HTML using a JQuery ajax call.  The plan is to create a view in the website which returns the data that I want for each page and then create a template for that view which outputs the data in the correct format for including.

I need to be very prescriptive with the HTML output which is where I am struggling.  I'm not overly familiar with Drupal templating and what I have done seems like a lot of HTML is created when outputting a node, and it is all also contained within the site template.  I need to be able to output exactly what I want e.g.

```
<div class="customclass">
   <?php echo($cckfield) ?>
</div>
<?php foreach($cckarray as $key -> $value) { 
   echo(some html using $key and $value);
}?>
```

Hopefully the pseudocode above gives an indication of the level of control required.  Is this possible using either core or with a module? Or do I need to roll my own pages and use the API rather than going for Views?

Comment: I can't exactly see your problem here. Are you talking about removing all the HTML generated by Drupal and replace it with a more light-weight construct? Or how to output the values that make up the page itself?

Comment: I don't want any of the Drupal generated HTML, literally just what I define in the template so I can drop this straight into a webpage

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that there are many files collected together and merged into the output file. If you want clean HTML, you need to go through the different files that make up the final output (e.g. page.tpl, different modules files,...).

The best way to change the base HTML-output is to filter everything that you don't need out of the `$node` object that every site gets passed. It also holds all the CCK values in formated and unformated form as well as all other fields. SO creating a custom template with no HTML and the bare values of `$node` should give you what you want.

Comment: How exactly do I do that though?  How do I stop the site.tpl and other templates in the hierarchy being used?  I guess what I am looking for is closer to an RSS feed than HTML output, maybe there is something along these lines?

Comment: You can't really stop it (at least I don't know how) since this is the way it is supposed to work. But as I said, in order to fully controll the HTML being generated, you need to override the default templates that hold the HTML and remove the rest of it from the `$node` object.